# WP - get the ticket list from tribe event calendar tickets

Tags: wordpress, event-calendar, tribe-event-tickets

I use the `event calendar` plugin with its `tickets` extension. I want to get a list of the emitted tickets. like:

```
array(
  0 => ticket 1,
  1 => ticket 2
)
```

I looked for a solution in the doc https://docs.theeventscalendar.com/ but impossible to find the answer.

When I try `tribe_tickets_get_attendees()` I get my attendees list with the tickets they bought but I only get the ones that has been bought, not the rest of the tickets available. i.e if people have bought `ticket 2` I won't see any mention of the `ticket 1` with `tribe_tickets_get_attendees()`.

Any ideas? its driving me crazy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tribe__Tickets__Tickets::get_all_event_tickets( $event )`

works for me.